# JQuery mobile single page or multi-page mode?

Tags: jquery-mobile, singlepage, multipage

How to know what mode of JQuery mobile am I using?
Is having `data-role="page"` is enough of multi-page mode indication?

Comment: No, but having *multiple* elements with `data-role="page"` would be a good hint.

Comment: _Single_ = page1.html, page2.html, etc. Each `data-role=page` in a separate file. _Multi_ = #page1, #page2, etc. All pages in one file.

Comment: @Omar could you post it as an answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several div with `data-role='page'` in your html file you are using a multi-page template, on the other hand if you have only one you are using a single page template.

If you got a multi-page template your link to page2 is simply refering to the second page id :

```
<a href="#page2">go</a>
```